# How to draw an ellipse on top of Panel?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to code an application that resembles a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), and I want to draw an ellipse to enclose a group of numbers.

What I have is a `JFrame`, which has a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`, where I add several other panels to it. So, in the end, I have a grid-like interface. I want the ellipse to be on top of these panels.

I am trying to use `Graphics2D` and the method `draw()`, but I cannot even begin to understand how to instantiate the `Graphics2D` object.

What I've done is: get the `Graphics` object from the `JPanel` with the `GridLayout`, then

g is the Graphics object.

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y,rectwidth,rectheight));
```

Then `repaint()` the gridlayout panel, but nothing happens and it doesnt throw an exception or anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate `Graphics2D`, you should override `paintComponent(Graphics)` from the `JPanel`, and do your drawing there. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509561/how-to-draw-a-filled-circle-in-java

Comment: Oh thanks, but how do java manage the `paintComponent(Graphics)`? I mean, can I just call it when I want to?

Comment: This method is called automatically every time the component gets repainted . You may call repaint() when you really feel the need to manually trigger a repaint, but I don't think you will have to.

Comment: I see, I'll try to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Look up `glassPane` or `JLayer`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516581/how-to-highlight-uniform-visually-select-draw-transparent-overlay-jpanel/27516784#27516784), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289157/java-netbeans-ide-overlay-images-chessboard-chesspiece/22289435#22289435), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703650/how-to-convert-jgraph-to-a-glass-pane/16704288#16704288)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is examined in [*Performing Custom Painting*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). The approach is to override the `paintComponent()` method of a suitable `JComponent` and render your content relative to it's current size when asked. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293513/230513) draws numbers; this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7824225/230513) illustrates overlapping translucent shapes suitable for such a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Alternatively, add suitable components, e.g. `JLabel` or `JButton`, to a `GridLayout`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513). Render the desired shapes in a `LayerUI` wrapped in a `JLayer`, as shown in [*How to Decorate Components with the* `JLayer` *Class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) and the examples cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315982/how-to-draw-an-ellipse-on-top-of-panel/37319505#comment62157701_37315982) by [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516581/how-to-highlight-uniform-visually-select-draw-transparent-overlay-jpanel/27516784#27516784), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289157/java-netbeans-ide-overlay-images-chessboard-chesspiece/22289435#22289435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703650/how-to-convert-jgraph-to-a-glass-pane/16704288#16704288).

Comment: Your "examples cited here" link points to your answers and not MadProgrammer's answer.

Comment: @BileshGanguly: Thank you for a helpful edit; although the comment link is correct, I've edited the answer to include the examples [cited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315982/how-to-draw-an-ellipse-on-top-of-panel/37319505?noredirect=1#comment62157701_37315982).

Comment: Thank you all, I was not using well the Graphics object, I could do what I wanted with that.

Comment: Glad you got it working; this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2545642/230513) draws on the glass pane.